# SQL Server: Getting value from an XML attribute with namespace different to element's

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an xml where there are few attributes with namespace but they are different to the namespace of the element they belong.

Sample Xml:

```
<d:dataroot xmlns:m="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-m" xmlns:d="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-d">
  <Books xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Books.xsd">
    <Book d:id="1" m:name="Book1" isbn="123">
      <Author>John</Author>
    </Book>
    <Book d:id="2" m:name="Book2" isbn="124">
      <Author>John</Author>
    </Book>
  </Books>
</d:dataroot>
```

With above sample, when I run the script below

```
DROP TABLE #TestXml
CREATE TABLE #TestXml (XMLDATA XML);
INSERT INTO #TestXml (XMLDATA) VALUES ('<d:dataroot xmlns:m="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-m" xmlns:d="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-d">
  <Books xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Books.xsd">
    <Book d:id="1" m:name="Book1" isbn="123">
      <Author>John</Author>
    </Book>
    <Book d:id="2" m:name="Book2" isbn="124">
      <Author>John</Author>
    </Book>
  </Books>
</d:dataroot>');

SELECT * FROM #TestXml
WHERE XMLDATA.exist('//*:Book[@isbn="124"]') = 1

--;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-d')
--SELECT * FROM #TestXml
--WHERE XMLDATA.exist('//*:Book[d:@id="2"]') = 1
```

Query 1 returns the expected result as the `isbn` doesnt have any namespace but when I run the commented query I get the below error

```
Msg 9303, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
XQuery [#TestXml.XMLDATA.exist()]: Syntax error near ':', expected ']'.
```

Tried different ways to specify the namespace for the attribute in the query but no success.

Does anyone know how to query an xml attribute that has a different namespace to that of the element that it is within? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be really careful with your XML namespaces.....

The `<dataroot>` elements define a `d` XML namespace which applies to this top-level element, but the `<Books>` underneath it defines a new **default** XML namespace `http://tempuri.org/Books.xsd` that applies to this node and its children.

Therefore, you need to use this query to get your data:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-d' AS d, 
                     'http://tempuri.org/Books.xsd' AS ns)
SELECT * 
FROM #TestXml
WHERE XMLDATA.exist('/d:dataroot/ns:Books/ns:Book[@isbn="124"]') = 1
```

**Update:** and if you want to base it on the `@id` attribute, use this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-d' AS d, 
                     'http://tempuri.org/Books.xsd' AS ns)
SELECT * 
FROM #TestXml
WHERE XMLDATA.exist('/d:dataroot/ns:Books/ns:Book[@d:id="1"]') = 1
```

If you want to base it on the `@name` attribute, use this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-d' AS d, 
                     'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-m' AS m,
                     'http://tempuri.org/Books.xsd' AS ns)
SELECT * 
FROM #TestXml
WHERE XMLDATA.exist('/d:dataroot/ns:Books/ns:Book[@m:name="Book1"]') = 1
```

Comment: thanks but running a query using isbn is not a problem. The trouble is using the attributes id & name in the query as they have a different namespace.

Comment: @TonyStark: updated my response - is that the solution you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Never occurred to me that I need to prefix the namespace with '@' for attributes. Thanks.